# How to make a Welcome Message

Tags: javascript

When the HomePage loads a message is displayed prompting the user to enter his/her name and surname. Another message will then show "Welcome Mr./Mrs. (name)" but it has to show either Mr. or Mrs. depending on the gender.

This is my code:

```
var x;

var name = prompt("Please enter your Name and Surname","Harry Potter");
var gender;
var male;
var female;

if (gender == male)
{
    alert("Welcome, MR. " + name);
}
else if (gender == female)
{
    alert("Welcome, MS. " + name);
}
```

Comment: You need to *ask* them their gender (or force them to enter a mr/mrs/miss ... (bad))

Comment: Use select box or radio

Comment: JavaScript won't work out the gender of a name for you. However there are [APIs out there](http://genderize.io/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use, but this is not smart at all. **You should not do this!**
Use a dialog window which can contain html like https://jqueryui.com/dialog/ or http://fancybox.net

If your new to javascript and jQuery you could use http://www.codecademy.com/learn to get you started.

```
        var name = prompt("Please enter your Name and Surname","Harry Potter");
        var gender = prompt("Please enter your gender","male");

        if (gender == 'male')
        {
            alert("Welcome, MR. " + name);

        }
        else if (gender == 'female')
        {
            alert("Welcome, MS. " + name);

        } else {
            alert("Welcome, Unknown gender ("+ gender +") " + name);
        }
```